# Link multiple pages using Jinja2 in Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm completely new to using GAE and Jinja2. I'm struggling to figure out how to create a new link to  static webpage within the templates folder. For instance:

/templates/index.html is my base template which loads localhost:8080
and I want to be able to reach /templates/mockup.html

Or, if possible, have it reach /templates/mockup/index.html where other css and js code is stored. Such as: /templates/mockup/css/main.css or /templates/mockup/js/main.js

I'm realizing that a simple

```
<a href="/mockup/index.html">Mockup</a>
```

or any other file path combination doesn't result in the desired behavior. I think I have to define this as a template somehow within the python code...?

Any nugget of information is appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles

Comment: In your `app.yaml` you can set any URL within your site, such as `/mockup/index.html`, to be served from a corresponding static file (or do it for whole directories in a single yaml stanza).  It's normally best not to mix static files to be served in the same directory as files that need to be accessed directly by your application code, such as Jinja2 templates, but you can do the mixing if you insist (though I wouldn't recommend it).